# select specific records using IN

Tags: sql, firebird

I need to select records that has ID = 10,23,30 so I wrote this SQL

```
Select * from mytable where position(id in '10,23,30') > 0
```

But the problem I get additional records where ID = 1 and 2 
Any ideas how to select only what I need ?

Comment: where id in (10,23,30)

Comment: was trying where with in but I did not wrote the Brackets !! Posted as an answer to reward you, thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No need for `position`, just do `IN`:

```
Select * from mytable
where id in (10,23,30)
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `IN` operator:

```
Select * from mytable where id in (10,23,30)
```